# Yandex Maps Api Key - как перейти обратно на тариф Пробный/Бесплатный?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Создал Apikey, немного попользовалось - понравилось. И случайно в кабинете разработчика в разделе Финансы нажал кнопку перейти на платный тариф. Теперь все мои ключи, в том числе вновь создаваемые, блокируются яндексом из-за недостатка денег на счету.

Я хочу дальше пробовать работать с apikey, как мне перейти обратно на тариф Пробный?

Comment: Задайте этот вопрос в службу поддержки Yandex.

Comment: если речь идет о js api, то ключи используются только для коммерческой версии, вернуть пробный тариф, конечно, нельзя. бесплатная версия работает без ключа.

Answer (score 0):

В настоящее время для работы с актуальными версиями JS API Яндекс.Карт api-ключ обязателен. При соблюдении [условий](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) следует получать в [кабинете разработчика](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/) бесплатный ключ и использовать его. Тестовый тариф нужен для проверки API перед покупкой и для разработки продукта с коммерческим сценарием использования.

Если вы случайно удалите API сервиса из кабинета привязанный тариф также удалится. Предупреждение об этом появляется при подтверждении. Отсутствие тарифа заблокирует дальнейшее использование сервиса.

Заново выбрать тариф можно, щелкнув по кнопке Тарифы в настройках ключа, однако, бесплатный тариф для повторного выбора недоступен.

Если вам нужно восстановить бесплатный или тестовый тариф — напишите об этом в поддержку Яндекса **maps-api@support.yandex.ru**, и его установят вам вручную. В письме желательно сразу указать, на каком сайте или в каком приложении планируется использовать API. Убедитесь также, что ваш сервис соответствует [условиям бесплатного использования](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/).